# Generate list of functions in loop with parameter based on loop counter to pass to mutate_at

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `mutate_at()` from the `tidyverse` to apply a list of lag functions to a group of variables. I would like to generate the list of lag functions in a loop, which seems like the quickest/clearest approach. However, instead of applying the list of `N` functions once each, `mutate_at()` applies only the `N`th function `N` times.

In the example below, `N`=2. However, instead of generating lags 1 and 2 of `x` and `y`, `mutate_at()` generates lag 2 of `x` and `y` twice.

What am I doing wrong? I am open to better alternatives but I would prefer to stay in the `tidyverse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# I would like to use mutate_at() to take lags 1 & 2 of variables x & y.
df <- data.frame(t = 1:10, x = runif(10), y = runif(10))

# First, I generate a list of lag functions for lags 1 & 2 to pass to mutate_at()'s .funs argument.
lags <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
    lags[[i]] <- function(x) dplyr::lag(x, n = i)
}

# Second, I add informative names to this list of lag functions.
names(lags) <- paste0('lag', str_pad(seq_along(lags), width = 2, pad = '0'))

# Third, I apply this list of lag function to x & y.
df1 <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(x, y), lags)

# However, the process above generates lag 2 of x & y twice.
df1
#>     t         x         y   x_lag01   y_lag01   x_lag02   y_lag02
#> 1   1 0.5698044 0.3292775        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 2   2 0.6831116 0.3272847        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 3   3 0.7219645 0.9417543 0.5698044 0.3292775 0.5698044 0.3292775
#> 4   4 0.1691243 0.7175634 0.6831116 0.3272847 0.6831116 0.3272847
#> 5   5 0.7625580 0.5500207 0.7219645 0.9417543 0.7219645 0.9417543
#> 6   6 0.1700005 0.3265627 0.1691243 0.7175634 0.1691243 0.7175634
#> 7   7 0.3595347 0.1533229 0.7625580 0.5500207 0.7625580 0.5500207
#> 8   8 0.3950479 0.6069847 0.1700005 0.3265627 0.1700005 0.3265627
#> 9   9 0.9006300 0.6709985 0.3595347 0.1533229 0.3595347 0.1533229
#> 10 10 0.9249601 0.1230972 0.3950479 0.6069847 0.3950479 0.6069847

# Here is the expected output (without the pretty names).
df2 <- df %>% mutate_at(vars(x, y), list(~ dplyr::lag(., n = 1), ~ dplyr::lag(., n = 2)))
df2
#>     t         x         y x_dplyr::lag..1 y_dplyr::lag..1 x_dplyr::lag..2
#> 1   1 0.5698044 0.3292775              NA              NA              NA
#> 2   2 0.6831116 0.3272847       0.5698044       0.3292775              NA
#> 3   3 0.7219645 0.9417543       0.6831116       0.3272847       0.5698044
#> 4   4 0.1691243 0.7175634       0.7219645       0.9417543       0.6831116
#> 5   5 0.7625580 0.5500207       0.1691243       0.7175634       0.7219645
#> 6   6 0.1700005 0.3265627       0.7625580       0.5500207       0.1691243
#> 7   7 0.3595347 0.1533229       0.1700005       0.3265627       0.7625580
#> 8   8 0.3950479 0.6069847       0.3595347       0.1533229       0.1700005
#> 9   9 0.9006300 0.6709985       0.3950479       0.6069847       0.3595347
#> 10 10 0.9249601 0.1230972       0.9006300       0.6709985       0.3950479
#>    y_dplyr::lag..2
#> 1               NA
#> 2               NA
#> 3        0.3292775
#> 4        0.3272847
#> 5        0.9417543
#> 6        0.7175634
#> 7        0.5500207
#> 8        0.3265627
#> 9        0.1533229
#> 10       0.6069847
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you looking for `df %>%  mutate_at(vars(x, y), list(lag = ~lag(., n = 2)))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I would like lags 1 and 2 of x and y. I added the expected output to my question. I can manually generate the lag functions with `list()` but I would like to save time, apply pretty names, and make full use of `mutate_at()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible tidyverse approach using purrr's `map` (could be replaced by `lapply`). The column names are set directly in the `.funs` argument of `mutate_at`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

## data
df <- data.frame(t = 1:10, x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
N <- 2

df %>% mutate_at(vars(x,y), .funs = {
  map(seq_len(N), function(i) ~lag(.x, n = i)) %>%
    setNames(sprintf("lag%02i", seq_along(.)))
})
#>     t          x         y   x_lag01   y_lag01   x_lag02   y_lag02
#> 1   1 0.26550866 0.2059746        NA        NA        NA        NA
#> 2   2 0.37212390 0.1765568 0.2655087 0.2059746        NA        NA
#> 3   3 0.57285336 0.6870228 0.3721239 0.1765568 0.2655087 0.2059746
#> 4   4 0.90820779 0.3841037 0.5728534 0.6870228 0.3721239 0.1765568
#> 5   5 0.20168193 0.7698414 0.9082078 0.3841037 0.5728534 0.6870228
#> 6   6 0.89838968 0.4976992 0.2016819 0.7698414 0.9082078 0.3841037
#> 7   7 0.94467527 0.7176185 0.8983897 0.4976992 0.2016819 0.7698414
#> 8   8 0.66079779 0.9919061 0.9446753 0.7176185 0.8983897 0.4976992
#> 9   9 0.62911404 0.3800352 0.6607978 0.9919061 0.9446753 0.7176185
#> 10 10 0.06178627 0.7774452 0.6291140 0.3800352 0.6607978 0.9919061
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table` where we use `shift` which can take a vector of values for `n`

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- c("x", "y")
nm2 <- paste0("lag", nm1, rep(1:2, each = 2))
setDT(df)[, (nm2) := shift(.SD, n = 1:2), .SDcols = x:y]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(t = 1:10, x = runif(10), y = runif(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach that is more like your original attempt; the problem was with your method for creating a list of functions. Here we use a function factory approach:

```
lag_i <- function(i){
  force(i)
  function(x){
    dplyr::lag(x,i)
  }
}

lags <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  lags[[i]] <- lag_i(i)
}


> df %>% mutate_at(vars(x,y),lags)

   t          x          y      x_fn1      y_fn1      x_fn2      y_fn2
1   1 0.41793497 0.89151484         NA         NA         NA         NA
2   2 0.01086319 0.83059611 0.41793497 0.89151484         NA         NA
3   3 0.97040618 0.02881068 0.01086319 0.83059611 0.41793497 0.89151484
4   4 0.73283793 0.07989197 0.97040618 0.02881068 0.01086319 0.83059611
5   5 0.36587442 0.93391797 0.73283793 0.07989197 0.97040618 0.02881068
6   6 0.91053307 0.37605878 0.36587442 0.93391797 0.73283793 0.07989197
7   7 0.52912783 0.33095076 0.91053307 0.37605878 0.36587442 0.93391797
8   8 0.65377360 0.85224899 0.52912783 0.33095076 0.91053307 0.37605878
9   9 0.51129869 0.82418435 0.65377360 0.85224899 0.52912783 0.33095076
10 10 0.94932517 0.65900852 0.51129869 0.82418435 0.65377360 0.85224899
```

Comment: Thanks! "Function factory" is the search term I needed.